# tinymce spellcheck list dropdown

Tags: tinymce

Is there a way to change spell checker language menu with selected language?. I have a language list drop down and when user change this drop down value to other language I wanted to change spell checker's language  drop down with selected language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not definetly sure, but it might be necessary to reinit your tinymce then.

You can try to change the language attribute of the tinymce iframe body element, this might be sufficient.

So you do on dropdown change something like:

```
var language = 'fr'; // language: 'en', 'fr', 'de', ... 
ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id')
var $body = $(ed.getBody());
$body.parent().attr('lang', language);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I can do that in using "tinyMCE.activeEditor.plugins.spellchecker.selectedLang = language;"
This will change spell check language internally but I want to show change in UI also. i.e When user clicks on spell check icon selected language should select with applied language in the list.

Comment: is the an internal tinymce event fired?

Comment: yes. using mentioned command we can change tinymce spell check language. But not affect on UI.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved. I am posting the solution if any one facing the same.

tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, tinyMCE.activeEditor.id);
then I have reintiated the tiny mce(i.e tinyMCE.init({....});)